# Purescript Halogen DeepPeek Child Instead of Grandchild

Tags: purescript, halogen

I'm trying to adapt this example https://github.com/slamdata/purescript-halogen/blob/v0.12.0/examples/deep-peek/src/Main.purs#L58 (relevant part copied below), but instead of peeking the grandchild I just want to peek the child, or in this case `peekList`. I also want to keep the slot type as a parameter in the peek function for `peekList`.

```
peek :: forall a. H.ChildF ListSlot ListQueryP a -> H.ParentDSL State (ListStateP g) Query ListQueryP g ListSlot Unit
peek = coproduct peekList peekTicker <<< H.runChildF

peekList :: forall a. ListQuery a -> H.ParentDSL State (ListStateP g) Query ListQueryP g ListSlot Unit
peekList _ =
  -- we're not actually interested in peeking on the list.
  -- instead of defining a function like this, an alternative would be to use
  -- `(const (pure unit))` in place of `peekList` in the `coproduct` function
  pure unit

peekTicker :: forall a. H.ChildF TickSlot TickQuery a -> H.ParentDSL State (ListStateP g) Query ListQueryP g ListSlot Unit
peekTicker (H.ChildF _ (Tick _)) = H.modify (\st -> { count: st.count + 1 })
peekTicker _ = pure unit
```

How can I actually peek `peekList` without losing the slot parameter?

I've tried removing the `H.runChildF`:

```
peek = coproduct peekList (const (pure unit))
```

and then adding back in the slot parameter to `peekList`:

```
peekList :: forall a. H.ChildF ListSlot ListQuery a -> H.ParentDSL State (ListStateP g) Query ListQueryP g ListSlot Unit
```

But then in `peek` I get the error "Could not match type ChildF with type Coproduct while trying to match type ChildF ListSlot with type Coproduct (ChildF ListSlot ListQuery)"

If I just try to use `peekList` instead o `peek`, i get the error "Could not match type Coproduct ListQuery (ChildF TickSlot TickQuery) with type ListQuery while trying to match type ChildF ListSlot (Coproduct ListQuery (ChildF TickSlot TickQuery)) with type ChildF ListSlot ListQuery"

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the types closer and saw that the second argument to peekList is a Coproduct wrapping an `Either` where the `Left` value is the list query that I want to peek. So just pattern match on those and add `peekList` to the component's `peek` parameter. Also I had to change the type signature to use `ListQueryP` instead of `ListQuery`.

```
  peekList :: forall a. H.ChildF ListSlot ListQueryP a -> H.ParentDSL State (ListStateP g) Query ListQueryP g ListSlot Unit
  peekList (H.ChildF _ (Coproduct queryEi)) =
    case queryEi of
      Left (AddTicker a) -> pure unit
      _ -> pure unit
```

Comment: You are right with this answer, but it's probably worth noting that the `peek` mechanism no longer exists in Halogen! (Since v1.0.0)

Comment: @gb. Yeah I decided to use 0.12.0 since there wasn't an updated halogen / purescript-routing example 2 weeks ago. Now there is, but I'm too far in